# How to prevent certain packages from being updated in CentOS?

Tags: centos, yum

I don't want certain package become updated in my CentOS system, so I did remove the respective repository of the package.

Now if I run system update and upgrade that package are not going to be updated or is there still a chance of getting updates even after removing the repository?

For example, I don't want Opera to get updated so I removed it repository still I get an alert kind of thing to update Opera to latest version, so if I do a system update then would it still update opera?

This is my repository list:

```
google-chrome                                                                                                                         3/3
home_tange                                                                                                                            2/2
repo id                                           repo name                                                                         status
base/7/x86_64                                     CentOS-7 - Base                                                                    9,911
elrepo                                            ELRepo.org Community Enterprise Linux Repository - el7                               249
*epel/x86_64                                      Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                    12,582
extras/7/x86_64                                   CentOS-7 - Extras                                                                    305
google-chrome                                     google-chrome                                                                          3
home_tange                                        tange's Home Project (CentOS_CentOS-6)                                                 2
nalimilan-julia/x86_64                            Copr repo for julia owned by nalimilan                                                78
updates/7/x86_64                                  CentOS-7 - Updates                                                                   632
repolist: 23,762


yum provides opera 

home_tange                                                                                                         | 1.3 kB  00:00:00     
nalimilan-julia                                                                                                    | 3.9 kB  00:00:00     
updates                                                                                                            | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
elrepo/primary_db                                                                                                  | 587 kB  00:00:20     
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.myfahim.com
 * elrepo: fedora.is
 * epel: repo.ugm.ac.id
 * extras: centos.myfahim.com
 * updates: mirrors.nhanhoa.com
epel                                                                                                                          12588/12588
google-chrome                                                                                                                         3/3
elrepo/filelists_db                                                                                                |  65 kB  00:00:00     
opera-stable-51.0.2830.55-0.x86_64 : Fast and secure web browser
Repo        : @opera
Matched from:
Filename    : /bin/opera



opera-stable-51.0.2830.55-0.x86_64 : Fast and secure web browser
Repo        : @opera
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/opera
```

updated my question ,now it looks like opera is the repo as this line says

```
Repo        : @opera
```

Answer (score 2):

To fix the version of a package, you should simply add to `/etc/yum.conf`:

```
[main]
...
exclude=kernel* redhat-release* whatever-package
```

Comment: actually i removed the repo for the opera browser but i still see this get latest security alert so my concern is if i restart my browser will it get updated as it happened once , but since it doesn;t have the repo so it shouldn't be updating technically

Comment: i have posted my repolist ,and i dont see opera in my repo so it mean it shouldn't be getting updated...

Comment: For opera it is correct, but generally speaking, it is not a good practice. If there was opeera in epel, your solution would not work, for example, or would require you tto give up all epel packages

Comment: okay got it but can you tell me how do i check if opera is in epel?packages or not ..

Comment: @krushnach Chandra, to check which a package or command comes from, you can use `yum provides <package>`. To prevent updates for Opera, you could configure `exclude=opera`.

Comment: @krushnach Chandra, to temporary disable an update you could use the `-x` switch in yum command to exclude package, e.g. `yum -x opera update`.

Comment: @krushnach Chandra, another option would be use the version lock plugin for yum (`yum-versionlock`).

Comment: i have updated my question with output please have a look and suggest me